# How to append multiplication result of 2 vars in table cells?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm prompting the user to enter a number for row and another for column, then construct a table using the given numbers and numbering each cell accordingly.

However, I want my final result to be displayed as a multiplication table, like the image below:

[multiplication table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIvtW.png)

And here's what my code looks like so far:

`var table = document.getElementById("table");
var temp = "<table border = 1 border-collapse = collapse>";`

```
for (var i = 0; i < row; i++){ 
    temp += "<tr>";
    if (i == 0){
        for (var j = 0; j < column; j++){ 
            temp += "<td height = 20 width = 40>" + (j+1) + "</td>";
        }
    } else{
        for (var j = 0; j < column; j++){
            temp += "<td height = 20 width = 40>" + (i+1) + "</td>";
        }
    }
    temp += "</tr>";
}
temp += "</table>";
table.innerHTML=temp;
```

Answer (score 0):

That is nearly right already. What you are looking for is to put `(i+1)*(j+1)` in the second `for` statement.

I'm not sure how you get your user input. Prompt is not usually a great way to get input but because you said that's what you used the example below uses prompt. The problem with it is that it blocks everything else: not only your own webpage, but the entire browser. If you have not done so already, you might consider getting your user-inputted numbers from an HTML form.

You might also want input checking code. I've included it below in a full HTML/JS solution. It gives the user 3 chances to enter a number for both the row and the column. If the user fails to do so, it outputs an error message.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

  <div id='table'></div>

  <script>
    var table = document.getElementById('table');
    var attemptCounter = 0;
    var maxAttempts = 2;
    var temp='<table border = 1 border-collapse = collapse>';
    var row;
    var column;
    while ((typeof row !=='number' || attemptCounter <= maxAttempts) && isNaN(row) ){
      var row = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the number of ROWS for your table:"),10);
      if(typeof row ==='number' && !isNaN(row)){break;};
      attemptCounter++;
    }
    if(attemptCounter >= maxAttempts+1){
      table.innerHTML = 'Error: expected NUMBER for number of rows';
    }
    if(attemptCounter < maxAttempts+1){
      attemptCounter = 0;

      while ((typeof column !=='number' || attemptCounter <= maxAttempts) && isNaN(column) ){
        var column = parseInt(prompt("Please enter the number of COLUMNS for your table:"),10);
        if(typeof column ==='number' && !isNaN(column)){break;};
        attemptCounter++;
      }
      if(attemptCounter < maxAttempts+1){
        for (var i = 0; i < row; i++){ 
          temp += "<tr>";
          if (i == 0){
            for (var j = 0; j < column; j++){ 
              temp += "<td height = 20 width = 40>" + (j+1) + "</td>";
            }
          } else {
            for (var j = 0; j < column; j++){
              temp += "<td height = 20 width = 40>" + (i+1)*(j+1) + "</td>";
            }
          }
          temp += "</tr>";
        }
        temp += "</table>";
        table.innerHTML=temp;
      } else {
        table.innerHTML = 'Error: expected NUMBER for number of columns';
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I wanted! There's just a slight modification I need to make and that is to make the inner borders collapse. I still haven't figured out how to do that in my script.

Answer (score 0):

Your code nearly works. If you change your `(i+1)` and `(j+1)` to `(i * j)` you'll see that the table created works, except for the first row and first column (as multiplying by 0 will always give 0).

However to deal with the multiplication with `0` in the first column and row there needs to be some conditional that checks if one of the values (either `i` or `j` are `0`) and then changes the value to `1`.

I've only changed what happens in your `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < row; i++){ 
temp += "<tr>";
for (var j = 0; j < column; j++){
        // Here I have split your temp string.
        temp += "<td height = 20 width = 40>";
        if (i == 0 && j ==0){ // if both i and j are 0 then add a 0 to temp.
            temp += 0;
        } else {
            // Multiply them together changing 0 to 1 (solving the 0's problem)
            temp += (i == 0 ? 1 : i) * (j == 0 ? 1 : j);
        }
        temp += "</td>";
    }
    temp += "</tr>";
}
temp += "</table>";
table.innerHTML=temp;
```

`i==0?1:i` is a ternary operator which is just like a little if statement. It checks if `i` is `0` and if it evaluates to true it returns `1`, otherwise it returns the value of `i`. [Read more about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

Putting it all together,
`temp += (i==0?1:i) * (j==0?1:j)` multiplies the values in the table together and also prevents multiplication with 0 in the headings.

Comment: for border collapse you can add the following. `table.setAttribute("style", "border-collapse: collapse;");`

Answer (score 0):

Build HTML as string is not bad but it is better to work with DOM model. Here is an example.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Build Table</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <style type="text/css">
        .tbl{border:solid 1px #ccc}
        .tbl tr:first-child td,
        .tbl td:first-child{background:#ccc;padding:4px}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        'use strict';
        function buildTable() {
            //get numbers from micro-form
            var rows = document.getElementById('rows').value;
            var cols = document.getElementById('cols').value;
            //create table
            var tbl = document.createElement('table');
            tbl.className = 'tbl';//it is better then inline style
            //note that HTML table has its own DOM model
            var tr = tbl.insertRow(-1);//insert new row
            //first row is special
            tr.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = 'X';
            //so treat it accordingly
            for (var i = 1; i < cols; i++) {
                tr.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = i;//insert new cell and set value inside
            }
            //remaining rows
            for (i = 1; i < rows; i++) {
                tr = tbl.insertRow(-1);
                //first column is special
                tr.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = i;
                for (var j = 1; j < cols; j++) {
                    tr.insertCell(-1).innerHTML = i * j;
                }
            }
            //well done. Place our table in a container
            document.getElementById('table').appendChild(tbl);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        Rows: <input type="number" id="rows" min="2" max="10" value="10" />&nbsp;
        Columns: <input type="number" id="cols" min="2" max="10" value="10" />&nbsp;
        <button onclick="buildTable()">Build Table</button>
    </div>
    <div id="table"></div>
</body>
</html>
```